# calculating the crc32 checksum of an array of floats in Python

Tags: python, c++, crc32

I am trying to compute the crc32 checksum of an array of floats in Python and then compare it to a calculated crc32 checksum in C++, for a single float I am using this code:

```
crc =binascii.crc32(binascii.a2b_hex(float_to_hex(386.18758683282005)[2:]))
```

with

```
def float_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', f))[0])
```

which gives `597302619` and this the same checksum I get in C++. But also I need to calculate the crc32 checksum of an array of floats in Python.

how should the code look like to get the crc32 checksum of the array? I tried adding the checksums of every single float but this gives the wrong checksum

Comment: BTW, you don't need to delete a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006843) and post a different one. You can just edit the original post in the future.

Comment: With all those digits that you're showing, are you sure you wanted to use `'<f'` as opposed to `'<d'` (along with a `'<Q'`)? You are throwing away most of your digits by converting to a 32-bit float, instead of a 64-bit float.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat for each number, using the last CRC as the second argument for the next `crc32()`. So something like:

```
crc = binascii.crc32(firststring)
crc = binascii.crc32(nextstring, crc)
...
crc = binascii.crc32(laststring, crc)
```

Given the example array in the comment, I get this in interactive Python 3:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import struct
>>> c = 0
>>> for x in a:
...     c = binascii.crc32(binascii.a2b_hex(float_to_hex(x)[2:]), c)
... 
>>> c
702039990
```

This would be what you'd get for the CRC-32 of that float array as a sequence of bytes, *if* those floats are stored in memory in big-endian order.

Comment: I still don't get the correct calculation, for `a=[9.18823936e+08, 5.31059343e+08, 4.43046153e+08, 7.08473767e+07, 7.09524442e+07, 5.18276120e+08, 5.05024291e+08, 7.78667910e+08,4.57535601e+08, 3.79406166e+08, 8.48611084e+07, 1.10692586e+08,5.00766225e+08, 5.24536209e+08, 5.14322241e+08, 2.70888994e+08, 2.43665508e+08, 4.32868185e+07, 5.18634647e+08, 5.12672740e+08,9.18668546e+08, 5.32219264e+08, 4.44385871e+08, 1.87693749e+08,3.45630556e+08, 5.06711559e+08, 5.17099590e+08]` I get `702039990` instead of `873391585`

Comment: Can you confirm that `702039990` is the correct crc32? I need to know which one is correct